# Did Final Crisis retcon Darkseid?

Tags: dc

I've heard, many times, around the interwebs that Grant Morrison stated in an interview about Final Crisis, that every appearance of Darkseid was just an avatar of his true form.

But I've never actually found where this is stated. Does anyone know where in Final Crisis, or what interview Morrison gave, that states this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that I can answer my own question. After a little digging, I found the interview in question.

Grant Morrison interviewed with *[Wizard Universe](http://web.archive.org/web/20090803004540/http://www.wizarduniverse.com/022908finalcrisis3.html)* regarding Final Crisis where he said:

> Superman, Batman and the Justice League know about the New Gods because they've met them, but we've never really seen the New Gods in their full power before. We've seen their actions. The DC superheroes see the New Gods as other superheroes in the way that Orion or Barda can join the Justice League. They've never understood that what they really are are f---ing gods. **This story's about the first time Darkseid actually manifests on the planet. Everything we've ever seen before has been kind of projections from the world of the New Gods and for the first time we're seeing them in their full power.** And it's like what would happen if a god appeared on the planet. Galactus is one god. This is a whole bunch of them; that's how bad it is.

Comment: Good find and welcome to the site.